# Returning from a function while inside one or more nested loops?

Tags: clojure

Is there a way to immediately return from a function when in one or more nested loops?

Here's some sample code illustrating the problem:

```
; Grid data structure
; -------------------
(defstruct grid :width :height)

(defn create-grid [w h initial-value]
  (struct-map grid
    :width  w
    :height h
    :data   (ref (vec (repeat (* w h) initial-value)))))

(defn create-grid-with-data [w h gdata]
  (struct-map grid
    :width w
    :height h
    :data (ref gdata)))

(defn get-grid [g x y]
  (let [gdata (g :data)
        idx   (+ x (* (g :width) y)) ]
    (gdata idx)))

(defn set-grid [g x y value]
  (let [data  (deref (g :data))
        idx   (+ x (* (g :width) y)) ]
    (dosync (alter (g :data) (fn [_] (assoc data idx value))))))

(defn get-grid-rows [g]
  (partition (g :width) (deref (g :data))))



; Beginning of test app
; ---------------------

; The Tetris playing field  
(def current-field (create-grid 20 10 0))


; A tetris block (the L-Shape)
(def current-block {
  :grid (struct-map grid :width 3 :height 3 :data [ 0 1 0
                                                    0 1 0
                                                    0 1 1 ])

  ; upper-left corner of the block position in the playing field
  :x (ref 0) 
  :y (ref 0)
} )


; check-position-valid checks if the current position
; of a block is a valid position in a playing field
(defn check-position-valid [field block]
  (dotimes [ x ((block :grid) :width) ]
    (dotimes [ y ((block :grid) :height) ]
      (if
        (let [ g           (block :grid)
               block-value (get-grid g x y)
               field-x     (+ x (deref (block :x)))
               field-y     (+ y (deref (block :y))) ]
          (if (not (zero? block-value))
            (if-not
              (and (>= field-x 0)
                   (< field-x (field :width))
                   (< field-y (field :height))
                   (zero? (get-grid field field-x field-y)))
              false ; invalid position, function should now return false
              true ; ok, continue loop
              )))
        true
        false))))

(println (check-position-valid current-field current-block))
```

Perhaps I'm approaching the problem too much in an imperative way.

**Update**
Ok, I found a solution:

```
; check-position-valid checks if the current position
; of a block is a valid position in a playing field
(defn check-position-valid [field block]
  (let [stop-condition (ref false)]
    (loop [ x 0 ]
      (when (and (not (deref stop-condition))
                 (< x ((block :grid) :width)))
        (println "x" x)
        (loop [ y 0 ]
          (when (and (not (deref stop-condition))
                     (< y ((block :grid) :height)))
            (println "y" y)
            (let [ g           (block :grid)
                   block-value (get-grid g x y)
                   field-x     (+ x (deref (block :x)))
                   field-y     (+ y (deref (block :y))) ]
              (if (not (zero? block-value))
                (if-not
                  (and (>= field-x 0)
                       (< field-x (field :width))
                       (< field-y (field :height))
                       (zero? (get-grid field field-x field-y)))
                  (do
                    (println "stop is true")
                    (dosync (alter stop-condition (fn [_] true)))))))
            (recur (inc y))))
        (recur (inc x))))
    (not (deref stop-condition))))

(println (check-position-valid current-field current-block))
```

It uses a mutable reference as a stop flag, breaking the functional style of programming. But I'm happy to have a solution. Feel free to share a better way.

**Update**
For those interested, I've finished a first version version of my [Clojure Tetris](http://stacked-crooked.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/PlayGround/Clojure/Tetris.clj) game. Feel free to give it a try :)

Comment: By nested loops, you mean a recursive structure (either actual recursion, or a loop-recur structure)? Or do you mean a sequence processor like "for" ?

Comment: @Greg Harman: I updated my post with a code sample.

Comment: Just a tip: you should introduce abstractions in this code (i.e. separate out pieces using fns and macros where appropriate) if there is no performance bottleneck here. The code as-is looks fairly complex and therefore more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested:

```
(defn position-valid? [field block]
  (let [g (block :grid)]
    (every? true? (for [x (range 0 (inc (g :width)))
                        y (range 0 (inc (g :height)))
                        :let [block-value (get-grid g x y)
                              field-x     (+ x @(block :x))
                              field-y     (+ y @(block :y))]]
                    (and (not (zero? block-value))
                         (>= field-x 0)
                         (< field-x (field :width))
                         (< field-y (field :height))
                         (zero? (get-grid field field-x field-y)))))))
```

`for` is lazy, so `every?` will only go until it reaches the first non-true value.

Comment: If the block-value is zero the iteration can immediately yield true and continue the loop. For the rest it's perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a loop-recur structure, you do some sort of check to see if you need to keep looping, and recur if you do, or return a value if you don't. In a while loop, you'd just make the predicate equal false. There is no break and continue in Clojure, because it doesn't make sense in Clojure.

I think you're looking for `loop`, and not `dotimes`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my post with a sample using loop/recur. It works, but it's a bit ugly because it uses a mutable reference as stop flag. Feel free to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Since in another question by the OP I proposed a different data structure for the playing grid -- namely a vector of vectors -- I'm tempted to show how I'd go about solving this problem with that representation. For the purposes of this problem, it seems easiest to me to use `0` and `1` to represent grid cell states. Adapting the code for the case of a more complex grid cell structure (possibly a map holding the number or a Boolean somewhere inside) would present no problem.

This is the function being discussed:

```
(defn check-position-valid [field-grid block]
  (let [grid-rect (subgrid field-grid
                           @(block :x)
                           (-> block :grid :width)
                           @(block :y)
                           (-> block :grid :height))
        block-rect (-> block :grid :data)]
    (and grid-rect
         (not-any? pos?
                   (mapcat #(map (comp dec +) %1 %2)
                           grid-rect
                           block-rect)))))
```

I removed the `grid` struct map; instead, all grids are simple vectors of vectors. Note that holding explicit `:width` and `:height` keys may not necessarily be much help performance-wise, as Clojure vectors keep a count of their members (as do many other Clojure collections). There's no particular reason not to have them, though, I just found it simpler to do without. This affects my terminology below: the word 'grid' always refers to a vector of vectors.

The following creates the grid on which the other functions operate; also enjoy the bonus printout function:

```
(defn create-grid
  ([w h] (create-grid w h 0))
  ([w h initial-value]
     (let [data (vec (map vec (repeat h (repeat w initial-value))))]
       data)))

(defn print-grid [g]
  (doseq [row g]
    (apply println row)))
```

The key to the above version of `check-position-valid` is this function, which gives as a subgrid of the given grid:

```
(defn subgrid
  "x & y are top left coords, x+ & y+ are spans"
  [g x x+ y y+]
  (if (and (<= (+ x x+) (count g))
           (<= (+ y y+) (count (first g))))
    (vec
     (map #(subvec % x (+ x x+))
          (subvec g y (+ y y+))))))
```

`subvec` is advertised by its docstring as an O(1) (constant time) operation which is very fast, so this should be pretty fast too. In the above, it's used to extract a window into the given grid, which is itself a grid (and can be printed with `print-grid`). `check-position-valid` takes such a window into the grid and examines it side-by-side with the block's grid to determine whether the block is in a valid position.

It is assumed that completely nonsensical argument values (negative `x`, `x+`, `y`, `y+`) will not occur, however in case the window would "stick out" of the grid on the right or at the bottom, `nil` is returned instead of `subvec`'s index out of bounds exception.

Finally, a definition of `current-block` usable with the above:

```
(def current-block
     {:grid [[0 1 0]
             [0 1 0]
             [0 1 1]])
      :x (ref 0) 
      :y (ref 0)})
```

And some utility functions (which all return grids):

```
(defn get-grid [g x y]
  (get-in g [y x]))

(defn set-grid [g x y v]
  (assoc-in g [y x] v))

(defn swap-grid [g x y f & args]
  (apply update-in g [y x] f args))

(defn get-grid-row [g y]
  (get g y))

(defn set-grid-row [g y v]
  (assoc g y (vec (repeat (count (g 0)) v))))

(defn get-grid-col [g x]
  (vec (map #(% x) g)))

(defn set-grid-col [g x v]
  (vec (map #(assoc-in % [x] v) g)))
```

The latter four can be used to build up a test grid quickly like so (the `2`s and `3`s make no sense in connection with the code above as it is presently written, but they serve to illustrate what happens):

```
user> (print-grid (set-grid-row (set-grid-col (create-grid 6 10) 1 2) 0 3))
3 3 3 3 3 3
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 0 0
nil
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a very useful set of general utility functions for manipulating grids. One problem that I think remains with the check-position-valid function is that the block-grid can stick out to the left, right or bottom and this does not necessarily mean that its position is invalid. For example the L-block defined above has a left column full of zeroes. So -1 is a valid value for its x position. Perhaps a nice academic implementation of check-position-valid won't be possible. Thanks for your very educative post!

Comment: You're welcome. :-) Re: blocks sticking out, I'm tempted to explore a different way to handle rotations; it could end up being conceptually simpler and would remove this problem as a side effect. You're certainly right that with those blank rows / cols in place -- which I completely forgot about -- the above would have to be modified to handle all cases properly. One possible approach would be to check the parts of the block which might stick out first -- they'd need to be all-zero, of course -- then verify the rest as above.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track by replacing the dotimes with loop/recur. Now, to get rid of that mutable stop flag:

1. Add a second variable to represent the stop flag to your loops, like

   ```
   (loop [x 0 stop false] ...
   ```
2. Do an if/then to see if the stop flag is true as the first operation within the loops.

   ```
   (if stop (println "I'm all done) (...
   ```
3. Deep in your nested code where you have the if-not test, have both branches call recur with the appropriate value set for false. To paraphrase:

   ```
   (if (stop-condition-is-true) (recur y true) (recur (inc y) false))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could replace the `dotimes` nested loops with an idiomatic higher order function that walks a collection of data and returns a boolean value. For example, I think [some](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/some) could help.